# Can't use WordPress Plugin Hooks

Tags: wordpress, hook

I'm using the WordPress plugin Ultimate member which has a hook called um_user_register which should happen after a user fills out a registration form. According to the documentation (https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1308-umuserregister) I should be able to use that hook and do my thing. Unfortunately nothing happens.

The code I have added to my theme's functions.php file:

```
//Ultimate Member - Extra stuff after user registers
add_action( 'um_user_register', 'my_user_register', 10, 2 );
function my_user_register( $user_id, $args ) {
    add_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_utlimate_member_signup', 'Yes');
}
```

Am I putting my `add_action` or function in the wrong place or is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Have you tested if the function is running? You could try `echo "hello"; exit();` in the function.

Comment: @disinfor Ultimately it will save some information to a different non-WordPress database. I used the add_user_meta to see if the code was being called at all and it didn't work. I updated my function
`function my_user_register( $user_id, $args ) {
    echo "hello";
 exit();
}`
and it does not echo Hello or exit. The next page loads as normal.

Comment: Interesting. According to the documentation, you are using correctly. You probably have, but I would reach out to the developer of the plugin.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I just ran into this problem as well.

Comment: @slacle Unfortunately I'm no longer working on the project and don't have access to the code. I remember that as I did more work I had problems with hooks in general not working and this was just the first one I noticed.